# How do I determine which network adapter my computer is using?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista, adapter

I just put in a new network adapter card into my laptop and would like to know if it is being used. How can I tell?

I'm running Vista.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up the **Task Manager**, go to the **Networking** tab, and you can see which adapters are being utilized.

Answer (score 3):

You can identify the adapter by MAC address (Physical Address) using the **ipconfig /all** command.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried an `ipconfig` in a windows command prompt (cmd.exe) ?

Also, when you open the **connection status** (right clic on your connection, then status), you will see how much paquet were sent and received.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to go into Network Connections on the control panel and turn off all the other cards, then check if you can still access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, ipconfig, d'oh!

I then went to Control Panel > Network Connections. Then I was able to disable my internal wireless card that was still being used and enable the external one.